# Llamaindex query working in windows but failing in linux

Tags: openai-api, langchain, llama-index, large-language-model

This code works fine in windows but the same fails in Linux. I get

RetryError[<Future at 0x7f75dfcc6fb0 state=finished raised AuthenticationError>]

error in linux.

I have no idea why this is the case.

```
from llama_index import SimpleDirectoryReader, GPTVectorStoreIndex, MockLLMPredictor, StorageContext, load_index_from_storage, ServiceContext
from llama_index.storage.index_store import SimpleIndexStore
from llama_index.vector_stores import SimpleVectorStore
from llama_index.storage.docstore import SimpleDocumentStore


import os

os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY'] = 'openapi_key'
class LLamaIndexEngine:
    def __init__(self):
        
        # Setup service context

        self.storage_context = StorageContext.from_defaults(
            index_store=SimpleIndexStore.from_persist_dir('csvindex'),
            vector_store=SimpleVectorStore.from_persist_dir('csvindex'),
            docstore=SimpleDocumentStore.from_persist_dir('csvindex')
        )
        print(self.storage_context.to_dict())
        # self.service_context = ServiceContext.from_defaults(llm_predictor=self.llm_predictor, storage_context=self.storage_context)
        self.index = load_index_from_storage(storage_context=self.storage_context)
        self.query_engine = self.index.as_query_engine(top_k=3)
    def query(self, query):
        res = self.query_engine.query(query)
        print(res)
        return str(res)
    
if __name__=='__main__':
    try:
        engine = LLamaIndexEngine()
        print(engine.query('give best dishes.'))
    except(Exception) as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: Resolved. I had to import openai. Then set openai.api_key = "OPENAI_API_KEY"